# SQL Server SPIDS go into a sleeping state and never recover

Tags: sql-server, spid

I have a long running stored procedure that is executed from IIS. On average this stored procedure takes between two and five minutes to complete because it is searching through a large dataset. (although it has take around 20 minutes in some cases)

Most of the time the stored procedure works fine but every now and then the SPIDS go into a sleeping state and never recover. The only solution I have found is to restart the SQL Server and re-run the stored procedure

[image]

The are no table inserts in the proc (only table variable inserts), and the other statements are selects on a large table.

I'm stuck for where to start debugging this issue. Any hints one what it might be or suggestions on tools that would help me find the issue would be most helpful

EDIT: More info added:

- The actual issue is the proc doesn't return the resultset. My first    thought was to look at the spids, they were sleeping but the cputime    was still increasing
- It's a .Net app so .Net Core 3.1 with ASP.NET Core and a Blazor UI.    The libary used for db connection is System.data.SqlClient I believe    System.data.SqlClient uses it's own custom driver. Calling code    below:

[image]

- The stored procedure doesn't return multiple result sets, however obviously different instances of the proc run at the same time.
- No limits to connection pooling in IIS

[image]

Comment: Some useful info to included: what language is the app, what driver is it using, what version, is connection pooling being used, implicit transactions, multiple active result sets?

Comment: Also what is the _actual symptom_? If the app has gotten its results what is the harm in the spid being there asleep? Does the app run out of connections or is it just less busy when you observe this so the connections aren’t needed/in use anyway? Connection pooling exists because it is cheaper to keep a connection open so it can be reused whe needed than it is to kill all connections for the purpose of … keeping dm_exec_sessions small?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for your comments, I have added the detail requested

Comment: Has the user navigated away from the web page? Have you tried returning results quicker, perhaps FASTFIRSTROW might help. Are you returning many rows? It is probably worthwhile tuning your query to perform quicker!!!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but you mentioned `System.Data.SqlClient` as the driver. You should be using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` in .Net Core. Sleeping SPIDs might be a red herring for your symptoms since those are normal with connection pooling. However, if you have many sleeping SPIDs with default connection pooling parameters, that is a symptom of a connection leak (maybe an artifact the issue). Are you using the exact same connection string and security context for all connections?

Comment: @DanGuzman I am using the same connection string and code for each request. If it is valid to have sleeping spids that are processing queries then it might be a red herring. I am unsure what steps to take to debug further. Could you recommend any resources for me to look at?

Comment: @RichardWatts, sleeping SPIDs are not processing queries. The are done on the server side, waiting for another query.

Comment: @DanGuzman well that throws a curve ball to my issue. I have queries that usually take a few minutes but are taking a lot longer with no results returned so Im unsure if they've crashed or are just taking a very long time. So I run sp_who2 on sql to investigate and find that spids that look like they should be processing the queries (are on the right db) but are in a sleeping state. 

If I execute more queries they suffer the same problem . Restarting SQL Server fixes the issue and future queries are executed in a normal amount of time.

Any ideas?

Comment: @RichardWatts, perhaps an exception (SQL timeout) is thrown but not properly handled.

Comment: @RichardWatts, the source of the problem may not be as you explained. If possible, try to run your long-running SP out of IIS, maybe a console app. I suggest that because your web application may lose the connection with the webserver and even your SP returns some data, you cannot see it in your web application. You can check your IIS logs to see if there is an issue like "connection aborded", etc. That may be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@RichardWatts when you say " re-run the stored procedure" you mean that the same stored proc with the same parameter and data works once you restart SQL Server ?

If so look over your loc (sp_loc} inside your table probably another process loc some data and doesnt release it properly, specialy if you have transaction accessing the same tables.
What is your your isolation level on your connexion ? If you can, try to change it to READ UNCOMMITTED to see if that solve your problem.
as an alternate you can also add a WITH (NOLOCK) or (READUNCOMMITTED) to your sql command.
Know that you will need to hold query with a read uncommited or nolock if you have some modification on the structure of your table or index re construction for example or they will in turn block its execution

Nevertheless be cautious this solution depend on your environment, specially if your tables gots lots of update, delete, insert,... this kind of isolation can lead to a Dirty read and doesnt adress the root cause of your problem wich I would bet is uncomited transaction (good article [that explain it](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/))

Make also a DBCC CHECKTABLE just to be sure on this side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Bashbone yes I run the same stored procedure with the same parameters after restarting SQL. 

Connection isolation would use the DB default which is Read Uncommitted. I am also using WITH(NOLOCK for a lot of the queries). I am not that concerned about dirty reads as data is not updated that reguarly

Comment: @Richard Watts and does your stored proc use the NOLOC? Try sp_loc next time, if you are in sleeping mode because of a loc that should tell it (Edited my answer to add it)